# JavaScript Ajax function returning error with status code 'OK'

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I do not understand why this ajax request is returning an error even though the error status is OK (200), any thoughts? It seems like I am missing something very obvious but I have been tearing myself apart trying to find an answer! I am new to ajax and therefore have little experience with it! Thanks for the help.

This is my ajax request:

```
    var dataString = $('#cform').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'contact.php',
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success == 0) {
            var errors = '<ul><li>';
            if (data.name_msg != '')
                errors += data.name_msg + '</li>';
            if (data.email_msg != '')
                errors += '<li>' + data.email_msg + '</li>';
            if (data.godaddyemail_msg != '')
                errors += '<li>' + data.godaddyemail_msg + '</li>';
            if (data.godaddyuser_msg != '')
                errors += '<li>' + data.godaddyuser_msg + '</li>';

            $("div#output").removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-error').show().html('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button><p> Could not complete your request. See the errors below!' + errors + '</p>');
        }
        else if (data.success == 1) {

            $("div#output").removeClass('alert-error').addClass('alert-success').show().html('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button><p>You message has been sent successfully!</p>');
        }

    },

            error: function (error) {
        $("div#output").removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-error').show().html('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button><p> Could not complete your request. The Function returned an error!</p>' + error.statusText); }
});

return false;
```

}

This is contact.php (where the request is sent to):

```
<?php 

$send_email_to = "My Email";
$message = 'message';
$subject = 'subject';
function send_email($name,$email,$godaddyusername,$godaddyemail)
{
  global $send_email_to;  
  if($message=='message')$message='';
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: ".$email. "\r\n";
  $message = "<strong>Email = </strong>".$email."<br>";  
  $message .= "<strong>Name = </strong>".$name."<br>";     
  $message .= "<strong>GoDaddy Username = </strong>".$godaddyusername."<br>";     
  $message .= "<strong>GoDaddy Email = </strong>".$godaddyemail."<br>";
  mail($send_email_to, $subject, $message,$headers);
  return true;
}

function validate($name,$email,$godaddyusername,$godaddyemail)
{
  $return_array = array();
  $return_array['success'] = '1';
  $return_array['name_msg'] = '';  
  $return_array['email_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['godaddyuser_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['godaddyemail_msg'] = '';

 if($email == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['email_msg'] = 'Email is required';
  }
  else
  {
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
      $return_array['email_msg'] = 'Enter valid emmail.';  
    }
  }

  if($name == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['name_msg'] = 'Name is required';
  }
  else
  {
     $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
     $return_array['name_msg'] = 'Enter valid Name.';
    }
  }

  if($godaddyusername == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['godaddyuser_msg'] = 'GoDaddy Username is required';
  }

  if($godaddyemail == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['godaddyemail_msg'] = 'GoDaddy Email is required';
  }

  else
  {
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$godaddyemail)) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
      $return_array['godaddyemail_msg'] = 'Enter a valid GoDaddy email.'; 
    }
  }  

  return $return_array;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$godaddyemail = $_POST['gde'];
$godaddyusername = $_POST['gdu'];

$return_array = validate($name,$email,$godaddyusername,$godaddyemail);
if($return_array['success'] == '1')
{
  send_email($name,$email,$godaddyusername,$godaddyemail);
}

header('Content-type: text/json');

echo json_encode($return_array);
die();

?>
```

Comment: Please make sure the server script response is valid json, server response will have php warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have two undefined variables on your `send_email()` function.

Here you have this **`if`** statement..

```
if($message=='message')$message='';   // $message is not available inside this function.
```

and here

```
mail($send_email_to, $subject, $message,$headers);  //$subject is also undefined.
```

Comment: As if I missed it! thank you very much, working fine now